# It is better to have a caching mechanism inside or outside of a Factory class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, functional-programming, oop

my question here is not strictly language related, it is more a general programming concept.

If I have a Factory class that has a method to return Parser objects, and these parser classes ,I know, do not need to be instantiated more than once per iteration cycle (outside of the factory, of course).

It is better, in terms of use and object separation to create a caching mechanisms for all the instantiated Parsers inside of the Factory, ie: during the method call, or outside of it, when the method has already been called?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you could define an interface for your `Factory`, and then have multiple implementations - one implementation could perform the caching internally to guarantee that a `Parser` class is only instantiated once. Another implementation could perform no caching and just provide new `Parser` objects whenever something asks for one.

Either way, I suggest you try to keep this logic inside your `Factory` implementations and have the rest of your application work with the `Factory` interface. This way if you decide later that you don't want to cache anything or that you need to change the way a `Parser` is instantiated, you only have a single point of object creation - inside the `Factory`. This makes it really easy to change the way you construct `Parser` objects without having to change every part of your application that wants a new `Parser`.

Once again - if you create caching mechanisms to operate outside of the `Factory`, then those mechanisms will be all over your code since you have to use them whenever you want to get a new `Parser`. If you decide later to change the caching mechanism, you're going to have to touch a lot of code, but if you do the caching inside the `Factory`, you only have to change the `Factory` implementation.

Comment: See also the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: @Tom Brito: I understand the principle, but you need to explain how it applies to this situation.

Comment: actually, I've posted it to anyone who see your answer, not specifically for you. The principle applies to the situation as he's asking if his class should have or not one more responsibility then it already have. By following this principle, the answer is no, the caching mechanism should be placed outside, in another class. Sure it will depend deeply on his project, but if he wants a pattern to follow, this may be a good one.

Comment: @Tom Brito so you're telling me that it's better to create a Caching class and keep caching outside of the Factory while @Shakedown is telling me the opposite and both of you have stated good reasons for that, now I should just choose...

Comment: If you make a `caching decorator` you dont have to change your code at all...just wrap your factory with the `caching decorator` and when your code asks for a new object the decorator decides if it returns the old cached one or a new one from the factory inside it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the problem: the clients of the factory class don't care whether the objects they receive are cached or not. So the caching logic **must** belong to the factory.

Moreover, when you implement this, you first implement the factory without caching in order to have something working fast (**Do the simplest thing that could possibly work**). Then, you implement caching. Note that doing anything else is a case of **premature optimization**. If the client classes had to know whether the objects are cached or not, your development process would rot quickly.

How you implement it is up to you. I like writing once a generic caching class and reuse it in situations like this, but you could think about other mechanisms. Besides, I don't do java and therefore I cannot state about what is better to do here.

(PS: I see a lot of design pattern noise in the answers to this question. Is this common among java people to always think in term of patterns ? There are no singletons to design, no proxy classes to write here, only a simple reasoning about which interface cannot change).

Comment: I already did as you said, the first implementation was without caching, I'm introducing caching now as a form of optimization and was wondering what approach should be best.
Yes, thinking in patterns is common in the Java world, it's the gang of four that shaped us all, luckily or not :)

Comment: @Lex: for me, design patterns have always mostly been either trivial stuff you could have come up with yourself, or workarounds for missing language support. Abusing patterns is turning *you* the programmer into a program. But they can help you come up with good design practice if you understand well when they apply and most importantly when they dont. I have the feeling that "java schools" (in France, the crappiest programming schools teach java, hence my unfounded prejudices about java) try hard to avoid making you think.

Answer (score 0):

As Shakedown stated, one approach would be to work against an interface and supply a caching implementation and a separate non-caching implementation.  This can get to be a bit cumbersome in some circumstances though (does your app really need two different implementations?).

If you have a number of classes like this, you might consider using a Proxy pattern.  The Proxy class will implement the same interface as the Factory implementation and delegate to the factory only if the object that would be returned from the Factory is not already in the Proxy's cache.

Using a dynamic proxy will extend this approach and allow you to implement caching wherever you want with very little additional library bloat (but at the cost of increased complexity).

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is about the contract the factory interface provides. These contracts can be validated using a test e.g. test 1 and changing implementations shouldn't break existing behavior. Writing a proxy as a cache breaks these contracts as it will fail on test 1. Therefore caching should be part of the factory and it should be from the start. See test 2.

1. Write at test to show that a factory creates 'fresh' objects.

   `var item1 = factory.Create();
   var item2 = factory.Create();
   Assert.NotEqual(item1, item2);`
2. Write a test to show that a factory caches objects:

   `var item1 = factory.Create();
   var item2 = factory.Create();
   Assert.Equal(item1, item2);`