# Can an Abstract Factory be responsible for "creating or finding an existing" item?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, abstract-factory

My Ruby code has a *Concrete Factory*, which builds some complex objects:

```
author = Author::Factory.build(email: "john@example.com")

class Author
  class Factory < BaseFactory
    def self.build(email: nil)
      # ... Some data preparation and defaults
      Author.new(
        email: email
        # Map and assign more attributes
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I've run into a situation where I either need to build a new one,
or assign one from an existing collection.  In
database-terms: an `UPSERT`, or in ActiveRecord: `find_or_create_by`.

And I am not sure if this:

1. Is a proper task for an Abstract Factory and
2. If the proper way to implement this is by passing the collection, or
   to make the Factory itself responsible for fetching it.

Passing it in:

```
author = Author::Factory.build(email: "john@example.com", existing: authors)

class Author
  class Factory < BaseFactory
    def self.build(email: nil)
      author = existing.find {|author| author.email == email }
      # If not found, prepare and build a new one, like above.
    end
  end
end
```

Letting the Factory find it:

```
author = Author::Factory.build(email: "john@example.com")

class Author
  class Factory < BaseFactory
    def self.build(email: nil)
      author = Author.find_in_existing_with(email: email)
      # If not found, prepare and build a new one, like above.
    end
  end
end
```

So: Should a Factory every be responsible for finding-or-building?

And if so, must the Factory be responsible for fetching the items that
it must match against, or should the caller pass them along?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889494/it-is-better-to-have-a-caching-mechanism-inside-or-outside-of-a-factory-class

Comment: In what (use) case would client code *not* know whether the corresponding Author already exists or not ?

Comment: @guillaume31: Author is the only one to know whether it exists already. The Author-factory can therefore ask it at the Author (second example) or leave the client to ask it to Author and then pass it along (first example), but in both cases, the Author is the one responsible for checking existence (`Author#==`, `find` etc. However, defining the conditions on which to check existence is the task of the one calling this existence-check. And I am not sure if the Factory or the one calling the factory should implement this.

Comment: @berkes What I mean is, you rarely present a form to the end user with just an `Email` field where they are not sure if they are going to create a new Author or retrieve and use an existing one... Especially for an entity that looks as important as `Author`. What's your business need regarding that ?

Comment: @guillaume31: the example is greatly simplified and abstracted. In reality I'm dealing with Settles, Lists, Members, MemberInstances, and so on. Which would require explaining the Domain model a lot more in depth and would muddy the discussion a lot. I tried to avoid "no you should not use a Factory .... or such meta-discussions" by keeping it example-level simple.

Comment: OK, I'll attempt an answer without knowing these contextual details - but it'll end up referring to the context anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory is a creational pattern, so clients will expect fresh new instances out of it.

Sure, what the Factory does internally is of no concern to consuming code. But if `Author` is a domain entity, I fail to see how an `Author`-building object could be used by consumers for anything else than the "real world" addition of a new author in the system.

Unless you want be semantically unfair and trick callers by reusing existing authors instead of instantiating new ones. But that doesn't look like something you would typically do in production.